# “By the power of dark light, I shall rise.” What is the accurate way to say this in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am looking for an accurate way to say the following phrase in Latin.

“By the power of dark light, I shall rise.”

Since context matters for an accurate as possible translation, I give said context by saying I plan to use the phrase in a song, as well as I kind of “catchphrase” that appears throughout my body of work (songs and writing). By “dark light,” I essentially mean using darkness as strength, darkness as a positive thing. Essentially, darkness as light.

Since it’s something that I plan on using regularly, I want to get it right, or as accurate as possible.

Thanks to any who can help and thanks for reading.

Comment: Hi Linoge, welcome to the site! I rolled back your edit since it is essentially a different question. Feel free to ask another question. Also, translation questions are generally better received if you show some evidence of research, e.g. "What is the difference between these two Latin words for light?"

Answer (score 1):

I chose to reverse the light/darkness. The 'dark' color words in Latin often have negative connotations.

"Vi Tenebrarum Albarum Supero."
I conquer/rise above by the power of white/auspicious darkness.

This translation seems like it might be what you're looking for.

"Circa/Apud Vim Tenebrarum Albarum Supero."
The power of white/auspicous darkness being all around, I conquer/rise above.

I like this translation better. It seems to capture the sense you're looking for. Dazzling darkness surrounds you, and yet you rise. Choose "circa" if you're emphasizing the physical space around you containing the bright darkness, choose "apud" if you're emphasizing the light darkness's closeness to you.

---

Don't take any of these translations at face value; there's context we as translators are missing, so these translations might be a little wonky when you use them in context. Many words for light exist, many words for dark exist, many words for rising exist.